# SQL Server Grant Execute to different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-grant

Is there any syntax available in the grant command that would allow something equivalent to

```
Use [SomeOtherDatabase]
grant execute to [domain\UserLogin]
```

What I'm hoping to do might look something like this:

```
grant execute On [SomeOtherDatabase] to [domain\UserLogin]
```

Which of course does not work...

NOTE: 
I am aware of the syntax
   `grant execute on [Something] to [domain\UserLogin]`,
but in this form, `[something]` must be an individual database object, (procedure/function), as in
   `grant execute on [database.Schema.Procedure] to [domain\UserLogin]`,
not all objects in the database. you can't do
   `grant execute on [Database] to [domain\UserLogin]`
and apply the grant for every object in the database.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this might help: [cross database ownership chaining](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/96688/76668) or [enabling-cross-database-access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-cross-database-access-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Charles you May Get Some help from Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081334/granting-access-to-one-db-to-users-roles-of-another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Granting access to one db to users/roles of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081334/granting-access-to-one-db-to-users-roles-of-another)

Comment: I am aware of the syntax `grant execute on [Something] to [domain\UserLogin]`, but in this form, `[something]` must be an individual database object, (proc/function), not all objects in the database. you can't do `grant execute on [Database] to [domain\UserLogin]`